# List all dates between range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've seen this asked before, but couldn't get an answer that worked.

I have 2 columns - `startyear` and `endyear`. I want to create a list of all years between the start and end year. So if the row has a `startyear` of 2010 and an `endyear` of 2016, I want the list to show 2010, 2011, 2012, etc.

Do I have to somehow grab the oldest `startyear` and newest `endyear` throughout all rows?

```
 SELECT StartYear, EndYear
 FROM TestYear
```

Comment: How are you wanting this list to be returned?  As a table?  As a comma-separated list?  Some other way?  Please show some sample data to illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I want it returned as a table with one column (Year) with each row being a different year.

Comment: How many rows are in TestYear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive `CTE`:

```
;With MaxMin As
(
    Select  Min(StartYear)  As First,
            Max(EndYear)    As Last
    From    TestYear
), Years (Year) As
(
    Select  First From MaxMin Union All
    Select  Year + 1 
    From    Years
    Where   Year < (Select Last From MaxMin)
)
Select  *
From    Years
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in a Stored Procedure.

```
SELECT * INTO #FileDates
FROM (SELECT distinct year(startyear) as year from filename ) 
SELECT * INTO #FileDates2
    FROM (SELECT distinct year(endyear) as year from filename ) 

select distinct year from #FileDate, #FileDate2
```

Also you might want to check out:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/119892/

Comment: This is not going to work in most situations. They want one row for every year between the earliest startyear and the the latest endyear. This just doesn't even come close to that.

Comment: You're right -- it only covers years for which there is data.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive cte to do this.

```
declare @startyear int = 2010; --or any other number or a select query
declare @endyear int = 2020; --or any other number or a select query
with years(yr) as 
(
 select @startyear
 union all
 select yr+1 from years where yr < @endyear
)
select * from years;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @t Table (StartYear INT , EndYear INT)
INSERT INTO @t Values (2010 , 2011), (2012 , 2016);
```

**Query**

```
WITH X AS (

Select MIN(StartYear) MinYear
      ,MAX(EndYear)   MaxYear
FROM @t
) 
Select TOP ((Select MaxYear FROM X) 
           - (Select MinYear FROM X) + 1)
    ROW_Number() Over (Order by (Select NULL)) 
    + (Select MinYear FROM X) -1 rn
FROM master..spt_values a 
         Cross Join master..spt_values b
```

Comment: @ConradFrix There are about 2500 different values in the spt_values table, if you generating more then 2500 values then this code will not suffice hence the cross join to generate 2500 * 2500 numbers , alot more than just 2500 .

Comment: @ConradFrix no mate it has duplicate values in spt_values, anyway I changed my code to make it more efficient and more accurate.